# How to change the Summary of a PreferenceScreen with an Intent on Java

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I am programming an application that uses **SharedPreferences**, one of them was a date, so I end up creating an **Preference** with and **Intent** so this acts like a button to another **Activity** on wich the user can select a date and time from pickers and stored the value as a  **String** on my **SharedPreferences**, so far so good.
However, I want my ***"Preference button"*** to load that **String** into it's Summary property implementing the **OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener**, I have been able to do it for my **EditTextPreference** objects, here's my code so far:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
// DECLARATION OF USED OBJECTS 
EditTextPreference userId;
EditTextPreference userName;
EditTextPreference hospital;
Preference dateTime;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.activity_preferences);
    //LOAD SHARED PREFERENCES
    SharedPreferences getData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    //ASSING EACH DECLARED CONTROL A PREFERENCE
    userId = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_userId");
    userName = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_username");
    hospital = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_hospital");
    dateTime = (Preference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_dateTime");

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // STOPS MY LISTENER WHEN A KEY CHANGES
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
// SETS UP MY LISTENER WHEN A KEY CHANGES
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // LOADS SHARED PREFERENCES INTO THE PREFERENCES SUMMARIES
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    userId.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("pref_userId", ""));
    userName.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("pref_username", ""));
    hospital.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("pref_hospital", ""));
    dateTime.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("pref_dateTime", ""));
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

//REFRESHES THE SUMMARIES WHEN A PREFERNECE IS CHANGED
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals("pref_userId")) {
        userId.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
    }else
    if (key.equals("pref_username")) {
        userName.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
    }else
    if (key.equals("pref_hospital")) {
        hospital.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
    }else
    if (key.equals("pref_dateTime")) {
        dateTime.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
    }       

}
```

This code does not generate any errors on Eclipse so it will allow me to test it but I get the app will just stop unexpectedly when I try to go into my **PreferenceActivity**

Error is on the **OnResume** and/or **onSharedPreferenceChanged** methods, any ideas on a workaround so I can display my saved **SharedPreference** on this **Preference** Summary by using this implement of **PreferenceActivity** or should be using another approch (Keeping in mind I have a min of API8). Thanks guys any help will be really appreaciated.